# Connect Wii classic controller to Mac X OS Yosemite

Tags: controllers, macos, wiimote

I am trying to map a Wii Classic Controller to my Mac (Yosemite) to play Minecraft. I got Wjoy which worked great for connecting my Wiimote to the Mac. I then got Enjoy2 for mapping the buttons, but I'm having trouble with the analogs. When I mapped to WASD, down and right worked but up and left did nothing. Mapping to the mouse caused the cursor to continuously slide either up or right. I tried looking for alternatives to Enjoy2. I found Joystick Mapping. I would mind paying for it as long as I knew it worked. Would Joystick Mapping work, or does anyone have any other solutions like how to get Enjoy2 to work or a different alternative? Thanks!

Edit: I've found Enjoyable which works better, but when mapping to the mouse, it will slide very slow in various directions when the analog stick is neutral.